# Scroll dos fragments en un activity

Tags: android, scroll, layout, fragment

[image: captura de app moovit]

La imagen que pongo es el ejemplo de el app moovit de la funcionalidad que me interesa implementar, si arrastras donde estan los tabs (paradas y favoritas) puedes hacer un scroll hacía arriba o hacía abajo y va creciendo el fragmento inferior o superior.

Mi pregunta es si ya existe un componente nativo en android para realizar esa funcionalidad con dos fragments en un activity (muy parecido a la doble pantalla con dos aplicaciones, pero con fragments) o debo crearlo por mi cuenta.

Saludos

Comment: Yo tengo algo similar usando TabLayout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout y un ScrollView.